# How to hide whitespace indicators in Vim

Tags: vim

Vim was showing some whitespace with commas and periods on a red background which I didn't want. After some googling I was able to get rid of the commas and periods by removing `list` and `listchar` lines from .vimrc, I was also hoping this would remove the red backgrounds it was putting in these places, but all it did was change that to white (see image).

[image]

Is it possible to completely remove the whitespace background indicators in Vim? My .vimrc settings can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/js6fTZMF) and the plugins I'm using are listed [here](http://pastebin.com/P15cpgPh)

Comment: What color scheme do you use?

Comment: @Flint my .vimrc is set to `color solarized` but I'm open to switching schemes if the above is a "feature" of solarized

Comment: I grabbed solarized theme from [vim site](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3520) and I don't have that white background problem when I tested it. Are you using the same solarized downloaded from that site too?

Comment: @Flint I just tried replacing my copy of solarized with a fresh one from the site and it had no effect. Also tried a couple other schemes and the whitespace indicators remained present. I've added my .vimrc above if that helps.

Comment: Did you test an other colorscheme? To change it, type e.g. `:colorscheme default`. If this doesn't have an effect this is caused by a plugin. Search for `hi` or `highlight` expressions in your (ft)plugin files or extend your question with a list of all enabled plugins.

Comment: I tested several different schemes and all had it. I added to the end of my post a link with my list of plugins. If it seems that's where the issue is I'm fine with disabling one at a time to find out which it is, but is there an easier way than moving the folder out of /.vim/bundle and back? (grepping for `highlight` yeilded far too many matches to be useful)

Comment: @Lasall - the culprit turned out to be the plugin `vim-indent-guides`, thanks much!

Comment: @Exupery: Yeah! Glad I could help you and you could solve your problem :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Lasall](https://askubuntu.com/users/13832/lasall)'s suggestion to check my plugins the behavior turned out to be caused by a plugin named `vim-indent-guides` - removing that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:`%s/^ +//` :)

Comment: If I'm reading that correctly wouldn't that just remove all tabs and whitespaces? I'm not looking to change the formatting, I want the spaces/tabs to remain, just without any visual indication they are there.